# Does Epictetus State "Only One Cause Motivates Us", Or "One Cause More than Others"?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, free-will, causation, causality, greeks

## 1. Question:

**From Epictetus, Discourses, 1.11, ([Perseus English Link](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/perseus-cgi/citequery3.pl?dbname=GreekFeb2011&query=Epict.%20Disc.%201.11&getid=1)):**

1. Is Epictetus implying there is ***only ever just one*** cause for our actions?
2. Or, is Epictetus arguing there is one cause ***which outweighs all others***?
3. **What is Epictetus saying this cause actually is?**

   - Our own ***Inclinations / δοκή***?
   - A combination of our own ***Assumptions / ὑπόληψις*** - ***AND*** - ***Principles / δόγμα***?
   - Or, is Epictetus arguing that our ***Principles / δόγμα*** are ultimately the underlying cause - for even those other two causes, (our own Assumptions and Inclinations)?

---

## 2. The Text, Epictetus Discourses 1.11:

Because ***ἓν / one*** is given emphatic placement, and because I understand ***ἐπὶ πάντων*** to indicate "Primacy / Importance", I read it as:

> **Ἐπίκτητος:** - ἀλλ’ ***ἓν*** καὶ ταὐτόν ἐστιν ***ἐπὶ πάντων*** τὸ αἴτιον : ... ἔδοξεν.
>
> **Epictetus:** - ***On the contrary*** - there is ***one*** cause, ***above all*** : ... our Inclinations.

---

### 2.1. But, [Published English Translations](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/perseus-cgi/citequery3.pl?dbname=GreekFeb2011&query=Epict.%20Disc.%201.11) Suggest Just One Cause:

> **Epictetus:** But that ***there is the same motive in all cases***, which moves us to do or forbear any action: ... to do right.

---

### 2.2. And Further, The Text Actually Indicates THREE Causes:

> **The Visitor:** Anything else, other than our ***inclinations / ἔδοξεν***?
>
> **Epictetus:** Nothing [but] ... ***inward assumptions / ὑπολήψεις*** and ***principles / δόγματα***. ... we will make make sure of our own ***principles / δόγματα***.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it (from 2.), Epictetus is saying that there is **one** "main cause," among several "possible" causes.  However, since what passes as a "main cause" at any **particular** time can **change**, then both statements "**only one** cause ..." and "**one** cause **more than others**" - are false.

I believe that a more accurate statement would be, "among all causes, there is always one [above all] that motivates us" [into action].

Comment: -**Guill** - +1, Thank you! **A.)** I had not considered rendering "ἐπὶ πάντων" followed by the accusative as "among all"; **B.)** I would like to find other examples of the syntax meaning that - but that is a very great solution to the problem - I will let you know if I can confirm it; **C.)** If you can think of any other examples like that, (references) - it would be helpful!